# How to add default message in facebook send dialog message box on friends invite

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, facebook

I need to send message to my facebooks friends which should include:
- default text message
- url
- my custom message
and I need to know to whom this message was sent.

Please advise how this can be done

Comment: please let us see some effort from you!

Comment: That is against Facebook Platform Policy and if you do it the most likely thing that will happen is that your app will be disabled. Read 2.3 at https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: I posted the exact same thing as answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

This states that

> Facebook messages are a channel for person-to-person communication, and **not for apps to send messages, or encourage people to spam their friends**. In general, games on Facebook.com should use requests when communicating in game status (its your turn), inviting people to use an application, or sending messages to multiple people. You should offer the Send Dialog in situations when someone might otherwise send an email.

So I doubt that what you want to do adheres to Facebook's policies, and therefore will likely trigger a deactivation of your app.

Comment: Are there actually chances of the app being blocked because of high usage of the send dialog? I'm using it on my website which involves  inviting people via personal message or groups.